# Data not showing in table from Json file

Tags: jquery, json

I have created a webpage and am accessing a Json data file with book data in it. I am trying to get the book data into a table. I am not getting data to display and the instructor is not much help. Please provide some pointers as to what I may be missing as my developer tools are not providing any errors. At this time, I am trying to get the title to gain an understanding of pulling in pieces of data.

JSON snippet:

```
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 2341,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "Wfan6L9RGgYC",
   "etag": "2Q+a2PelwkI",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/Wfan6L9RGgYC",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "The Modern Web",
    "subtitle": "Multi-device Web Development with HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript",
    "authors": [
     "Peter Gasston"
    ],
    "publisher": "No Starch Press",
    "publishedDate": "2013",
    "description": "Provides information on Web development for multiple devices, covering such topics as structure and semantics, device APIs, multimedia, and Web apps.",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9781593274870"
     },
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lee Baldwin - Milestone 1a</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //retrieve data from json file
                $.getJSON("./json/google-books-search.json",function(bookData) {
                    var books = "";

                    //loop through bookData records
                    $.each(bookData, function(key, value){
                        //construct rows and cells of data
                        books += "<tr>";
                        books += "<td>" + value.title + "</td>";
                        books += "</tr>"
                    });

                    //insert rows into books table
                    $("#tableBooks").append(books);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <table id="tableBooks">
        
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (if needed)

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: yellow;
}

article {
    margin: 5px;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
}

#tablebooks{
    background-color:aliceblue;
    color: black;
}
```

Thank you for your help and patience. I am essentially having to teach myself while paying for a college course.

Comment: Are you running this on a server or just in your browser from a file?  Just at first glance, I think you might have a CORS issues.  Can you list your console errors?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, here are the 2 errors:
```
leebaldwin_milestone1a.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/lbald/OneDrive/Documents/College%20Docs/IT%204403/Milestone%201/json/google-books-search.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
jquery.min.js:2

GET file:///C:/Users/lbald/OneDrive/Documents/College%20Docs/IT%204403/Milestone%201/json/google-books-search.json net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Running in browser.

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic I resolved the issue with the CORS, but now I am getting the following message:
'
leebaldwin_milestone1a.html:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at String.<anonymous> (leebaldwin_milestone1a.html:21)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (leebaldwin_milestone1a.html:18)
    at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lee Baldwin - Milestone 1a</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //retrieve data from json file
                $.getJSON("./json/google-books-search.json",function(bookData) {
                    var books = "";

                    //loop through bookData records
                    // **** Change value.title to value.items.title ****
                    $.each(bookData, function(key, value){
                        //construct rows and cells of data
                        books += "<tr>";
                        books += "<td>" + value.items.title + "</td>";
                        books += "</tr>"
                    });

                    //insert rows into books table
                    $("#tableBooks").append(books);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <table id="tableBooks">
        
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thomson, I changed the line but it still does not work. I am running this in the browser currently because I cant reach mywebsite from where I am currently.

Comment: Try use console.log to see what is the display result for books variable.  See example below to know how to use console.log to debug in the browser.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-console-log-with-examples/#:~:text=The%20console.,be%20displayed%20to%20the%20user.

Comment: Thanks Thomson. I resolved this one and got it displaying the top 10 books on the page. My next goal once the semester is over is to use the 2 weeks before fall to learn how to get it to allow me to paginate all of the results on my site. I am also learning how to use CSS grid to position with. I have always just used table code to position elements, so this should be fun.